# Undefined function in module

Tags: 7

I use `taxonomy_get_term_by_name()` in one of my modules, and it throws a *Undefined function* exception.
My best guess is that this is due to Drupal core system not being ready for function calls. I've looked all over and I can't find any way to check when the core system is ready for function calls.

Do you have any suggestion?

The module uses `require_once` to get the file with the function mentioned above.

The content of the file calling `taxonomy_get_term_by_name()` is the following.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function functions_init()
{
    get_tids();
}

function get_tids()
{
    $terms = ['term1', 'term2', 'term3'];
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $result = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term);
        $GLOBALS[$term] = key($result);
    }
}
```

- This was not an issue when the module was developed, but with a few days of downtime on localhost and a reboot, this started happening.
- There is near certainly a workaround through use of EntityFieldQuery,  but I would like to know whether it is possible to check Drupal 7 core availability, which would be useful/needed in other situations.

Comment: This `get_tids($terms = ['term1', 'term2']) { ... }` doesn't seem make much sense. 

Comment: The shown code would not work, as it contains a parsing error. That is why @leymannx said it doesn't make much sense. If you are asking about code you wrote, you should show the code you are effectively using.

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood.

Comment: Now it's just missing the code that calls `get_tids()`, which I hope it's inside a function.

Comment: The question is still not showing the code you are using. As for description, the module is using `require_once` to load the file containing the function, but that part isn't show in the question.